# XNA Get the nearest distance between a object and a list of objects

Tags: c#, xna, position

I have a list of a object called Block, this Block has a position set as Vector2. And I have a object called Player which has a Vector2 called position, so I have many blocks in the screen and I want to get the nearest block from the object. How can I do that?

```
 List<Block> Blocks = new List<Block>();
 Player player;
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could've researched this a little more, but what you could try to use is `Linq` to get the closest block. Pseudo-code:

```
Block closestblock = Blocks.OrderBy<Block, float>
    (i => Vector3.Distance(i.Position, player.Position)).ToList<Block>()[0];
```

This will order the block list by the distance from the player and then take the closest block.

Based on your last comment, here is another way to do what you're trying. You'll have to create a rectangle around your player and each block. In your update method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Blocks.Count; i++)
    if (PlayerRect.Intersects(Blocks[i].Rect)) Blocks.RemoveAt(i);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle_members.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx). HTH

Comment: Thanks, but I have a list of blocks and everytime when I get the nearest block, this block is removed, So I need to get the next nearest block,How can I do that? I tried:

     for(int c =0; c < blocks.Count;c++){
     Block closestblock = Blocks.OrderBy<Block, float>
    (i => Vector3.Distance(i.Position, player.Position)).ToList<Block>()[c];
     }

Comment: Are you sure this is removing the block from your list? As far as I know, it shouldn't. Are you accidentally removing the block in a later part of the code? Also, with the code snippet you have, you should need to use a loop if you user `OrderBy`.

Comment: Yes, It is removing, So i need to find a new nearest blocks of my list. I dont know how can I do that.

Comment: If you're _certain_ that the item is being removed (have you tried setting a breakpoint the line after the sort and checking if the item's removed then?), then you could try creating a copy of the list like `var temp = Blocks; Block closestblock = temp.OrderBy<Block, float>
    (i => Vector3.Distance(i.Position, player.Position)).ToList<Block>()[0];` Or place `AsEnumberable().` between the `Blocks.` and `OrderBy` As a side note, does the answer I gave you find the closest block?

Comment: Yes, u gave the first block, but when it is removed, I cant get a new nearest block. I have to do a loop , I cant create everytime a new variable, is there any way that i Can do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you'd need a loop...the code I gave you should search the whole list and find the closest one. As for the item being removed, I have no idea why that would happen. maybe you could try `Blocks.Add(closestblock);` after the linq statement to add the block back into the list? If you could post more relevant code that would help.

Comment: Ok.I will exaplain what Im trying to do: Im making a game that there is a player and this player has to hit the blocks that spawn in the top of the scrren.I wont controll him.So every 10 secounds a new block will appear, then the player needs to go to the right position of the block that is falling.If the player intersects the block, this block will be removed.